# What is the meaning of ps process names printed in [] such as [cgroup]?

Tags: linux, ps

when I do a command such as ps -aux on CentOS 6 I get a bunch of processes whos command is listed in [] as shown below. What is the meaning of the [] in the name? I am assuming that these are special processes of some kind, what makes a process name show up with 
a [] around it?

```
[root@centos6 src]# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 18:48 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 18:48 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 18:48 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root         4     2  0 18:48 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 18:48 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root         6     2  0 18:48 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
root         7     2  0 18:48 ?        00:00:02 [events/0]
```

Comment: The answers below are right, I just want to add that those processes in square brackets on top of your output are `kernel threads` - those are actually processes, rather than threads, running in the kernel mode and having only kernel part of virtual address space (only upper 1 Gb, corresponding to addresses `0xC000000` - `0xFFFFFFFF` in 32-bit mode, cause they are not meant to access userspace at all). For instance, ksoftirqd is a daemon, responsible for running the bottom halves of interrupts, when the CPU is not busy with more urgent tasks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the command line is inaccessible to `ps`, i.e. `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` returns an empty string then `ps` wraps it in square brackets.

You can use this to test the above, by running the following command and then checking it out in the process list:

```
$ perl -e '$0 = ""; sleep'
```

Then do a `ps`:

```
saml     26756  2098  0 21:21 pts/9    00:00:00 []
```

Sure enough our `perl` process shows up with the square brackets (`[]`).

#### cmdline's are empty, really?

Yeah seems a bit odd but just to confirm I checked the first couple and they're definitely empty:

```
$ for i in `seq 2125`;do [ -e /proc/$i/cmdline ] || continue; \
    echo -n "PID# $i: "; echo $(cat /proc/$i/cmdline);done | less

PID# 1: /sbin/init
PID# 2: 
PID# 3: 
PID# 4: 
PID# 5: 
PID# 15: 
...
PID# 1187: /sbin/rsyslogd-c4
PID# 1189: /sbin/rsyslogd-c4
PID# 1190: /sbin/rsyslogd-c4
PID# 1211: 
PID# 1229: irqbalance
PID# 1255: rpcbind
PID# 1269: mdadm--monitor--scan-f--pid-file=/var/run/mdadm/mdadm.pid
...
```

#### Getting rid of them?

If you use the `-f` and `-c` switches you can see the expanded version of these processes without the square brackets:

```
$ ps --version
procps version 3.2.8

$ ps -auxfc | less
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00 kthreadd
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:04  \_ ksoftirqd/0
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:03  \_ migration/0
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ watchdog/0
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:04  \_ events/0
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ cpuset
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ khelper
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ netns
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ async/mgr
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ pm
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ sync_supers
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ bdi-default
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ kintegrityd/0
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:07  \_ kblockd/0
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ kacpid
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ kacpi_notify
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ kacpi_hotplug
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ ata_aux
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ ata_sff/0
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ khubd
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ kseriod
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:35  \_ kswapd0
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Aug21   0:00  \_ ksmd
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ aio/0
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ crypto/0
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ scsi_eh_0
root        60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:26  \_ scsi_eh_1
root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ scsi_eh_2
root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ scsi_eh_3
root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ scsi_eh_4
root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ scsi_eh_5
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ kpsmoused
root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00  \_ kstriped
```

From the man page for `ps`:

```
   -c    Show different scheduler information for the -l option.

   -f    does full-format listing. This option can be combined with many 
         other UNIX-style options to add additional columns. It also 
         causes the command arguments to be printed. When used with -L, 
         the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be 
         added. See the c option, the format keyword args, and the format 
         keyword comm.
```